# How to stop $location.url from auto decoding query

Tags: angularjs

I am using following query `"/search/queryText=at%26t/results"` to redirect to a page.

The location url auto decodes it to  `"/search/queryText=at&t/results"`. I need the value to be pristine, so that I can make use of $location.search to create an object of parameters.

The `$location.search` treats & as delimiter and creates two parameters (`queryText=at and t=true`)rather than one for the above example. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Get it from the "original" `location` object maybe? (But don't expect to find it in that one's `search` property, because there is no actual query string in your URL as it seems - so you might rather be looking for `path`, and go parse that.)